# I cannot perform math operation on data in qtablewidget cells

Tags: math, floating-point, sum, qtabwidget

My OS - Fedora
QtCreator Qt4.8

My Qtablewidget has floats in 50 rows in column 2

I am trying to sum the values in those 50 cells, my return local is 'nan'  I'm puzzled.
the data looks like this which was generated by the qDebug << tlocal;

0
0
0
0
0.11
0.062
0.12
0.11
0.21
0.22
0.11
0.15
0.24
0.14
0.046
0.16
0.36
0.14
0
0.015
0.015
0.13
0.1
0.0197
0.0262
0.14
0.04
0.001
0.0002
0.002
0.00016
1.18e-05
2.96e-05
3.01205e-05
4.5e-07
0.001
5.4e-05
7.4e-08
1.71e-07
4.9e-08
5.7e-07
4.9e-07
1.15e-12
8.9e-12
0
5.6e-05

My function is here

```
float MainWindow::sum_requirements()
{
    float local;
    float tlocal = 0;
    bool ok;

    for (int i=0; i < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); ++i)
    {


        tlocal = ui->tableWidget->item(i, 2)->text().toFloat(&ok);

        qDebug() << tlocal;

        local = local + tlocal;
    }

    qDebug() << "Before return = " << local;

    return local;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`float local;` lacks an initial value.

Use `float local = 0;`.

---

Naming: consider renaming `local` to `sum` to add clairty.